# Getting a map with points, using ggmap and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want a map with points (and other geom_* layers) on it. I get the map, but instead of the points all I get is a warning:

```
Message d'avis :
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Here is a reproducible exemple:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat=c(50.659631, 50.607213, 50.608129),
                lon=c(3.09319, 3.011473, 3.031529))

Lille <- get_map("Lille,France", zoom=12)

p <- ggmap(Lille)
p <- p + geom_point(data=d, aes(lat, lon))
p
```

Looking in the output of

```
ggplot_build(p)
```

I see a layer with NAs for x and y, but I do not get why the data from d is not considered.

When using ggplot() instead of ggmap(), I do get the points. But I do need the map too :)

So, how can I get a **map** with **points** over it?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your longitude and latitude values in `geom_point()` are in wrong order. `lon` should be as `x` values and `lat` as `y` values.

```
 p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=5)
```

Answer (score 26):

It seems you just inverted longitude and latitude :

```
p <- ggmap(Lille)
p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="red", size=30, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was sure that there is a simple solution :)

Comment: @Costin Please accept Didzis Elferts' answer instead of mine, I think he answered first.

Comment: OK, I see your message listed first, but if you say so I'll accept his answer. You must be in the same second, I guess :)