# Adding geom_point to ggmap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Assume the following minimal data set.

```
ddf <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia"), 
x1 = c(16L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 4L), x2 = c(1150.36, 9506.12, 7534.06, 6247.28, 18749.34, 6190.75)), 
.Names = c("Country", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame", 
na.action = structure(2L, .Names = "2", class = "omit"))
```

I borrowed code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136868/plot-map-with-values-for-countries-as-color-in-r) to generate the initial map.  I am assigning color to the countries based on the x1 variable as follows:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_simpl@data$id <- wrld_simpl@data$NAME
wrld <- fortify(wrld_simpl, region="id")
wrld <- subset(wrld, id != "Antarctica") # we don't rly need Antarctica
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=ddf, map=wrld, aes(map_id=Country, fill=x1),  color="white", size=0.25)
```

I want to add `geom_point` to each one of these countries, and set the size of the geom equal to my `x2` variable.  I'm not quite sure how this is done.  My thinking has been guided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069963/getting-a-map-with-points-using-ggmap-and-ggplot2), but so far no luck.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a set of coordinates - the centres or centroids for each country. `wrld` contains long and lat for the boundaries (polygons) for each country. A simple method for calculating centroids is to take the mean of the range of the long and lat values for each country.

```
ddf <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia"), 
x1 = c(16L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 4L), x2 = c(1150.36, 9506.12, 7534.06, 6247.28, 18749.34, 6190.75)), 
.Names = c("Country", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame", 
na.action = structure(2L, .Names = "2", class = "omit"))

library(RColorBrewer)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_simpl@data$id <- wrld_simpl@data$NAME
wrld <- fortify(wrld_simpl, region="id")
wrld <- subset(wrld, id != "Antarctica") # we don't rly need Antarctica

# Select the countries
SelectedCountries = subset(wrld, id %in% c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia"))

# Get their centres
CountryCenters <- aggregate(cbind(long, lat) ~ id, data = SelectedCountries, 
                    FUN = function(x) mean(range(x)))

# Merge with the DDf data frame
ddf = merge(ddf, CountryCenters, by.x = "Country", by.y = "id")

gg <- ggplot() +
   geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25) +
   geom_map(data=ddf, map=wrld, aes(map_id=Country, fill = x1), size=0.25) +
   geom_point(data=ddf, aes(x=long, y=lat, size = x2), colour = "red")     # plot the points
```

For better centring, you can use the `Polygon` function from the `sp` package, as demonstrated here: [stackoverflow.com/.../improve-centering-county-names-ggplot-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441778/improve-centering-county-names-ggplot-maps). It gets Argentina wrong, but I think it is something to do with islands. In `wrld`, I think `piece==1` selects the mainland, but it might not work for all countries.

```
ddf <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia"), 
x1 = c(16L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 4L), x2 = c(1150.36, 9506.12, 7534.06, 6247.28, 18749.34, 6190.75)), 
.Names = c("Country", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame", 
na.action = structure(2L, .Names = "2", class = "omit"))

library(RColorBrewer)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_simpl@data$id <- wrld_simpl@data$NAME
wrld <- fortify(wrld_simpl, region="id")
wrld <- subset(wrld, id != "Antarctica") # we don't rly need Antarctica

# Select the countries
SelectedCountries = subset(wrld, id %in% c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia"))


# Function to calculate centroids
GetCentroidPoint <- function(SelectedCountries) {Polygon(SelectedCountries[c('long', 'lat')])@labpt}

# Apply the function to the selected countries
centroids = by(subset(SelectedCountries, piece == 1), factor(subset(SelectedCountries, piece == 1)$id), GetCentroidPoint) 

# Convert list to data frame
centroids <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", centroids)  
names(centroids) <- c('long', 'lat') 
centroids$Country = row.names(centroids)

# Merge with DDF
ddf = merge(ddf, centroids, by = 'Country')


gg <- ggplot() +
   geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25) +
   geom_map(data=ddf, map=wrld, aes(map_id=Country, fill = x1), size=0.25) +
   geom_point(data=ddf, aes(x=long, y=lat, size = x2), colour = "red")
```

[image]